# jquery Passing ID tag across pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When my main page loads, it grabs the first entry with the id="vids" from videos.html.

**Main Page:**

```
<div id="sidevideos" class="sidevideos">

<script>
$('#sidevideos').load('videos.html .vids:lt(1)');
</script>
</div>
```

That works great, no problem.

I would like to be able to pass the video link( .vids) to this function on the main page

```
<script>
      var $v = jQuery.noConflict(); 
       $v(document).ready(function() {
                $v('#vids').colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600});

   });
</script>
```

Which would open the youtube video in an iframe.

**Video.html Code**:

```
<div class="videos">

 <a id='vids' href="youtubevideo"><img src="img/videos/housing.png" border="0" class="sidevids">
 <p class="sidevidtext">vid description</p></a>

 <a id='vids' href="youtubevideo"><img src="img/videos/housing.png" border="0" class="sidevids">
 <p class="sidevidtext">vid description</p></a>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems

1. `id` should be unique in a document, means you cannot have two elements with the same id `vids`
2. You need to call the `colorbox` after the `videos.html` is loaded, for that you can use the load complete callback

Try

```
$('#sidevideos').load('videos.html .eq(0)', function(){
     $v('#vids').colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600});
});
```

Comment: This worked perfect, just adding the function to the .load code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you wanted but you could store the link into a variable like this `var link = $('#vids').attr('href');` and then use the var to load in your main page

[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2nY89/55/)